# How to define two word in spacing

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch coding as below:

```
"query": {  
  "constant_score" : {
       "filter" : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
          {
             "terms": {"stkno" : ["Net Asset","asset combine"]}}, 
 { "range": { "CDate": {  "gte": "2015-01-01" ,  "lte": "2017-06-03T23:59:59"  } } } ]

    }}}}
```

this is mapping:

```
{
  "news": {
  "mappings": {
     "bursa": {
        "_timestamp": {},
        "properties": {
           "CDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "epoch_millis||dateOptionalTime"
           },
           "RDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "epoch_millis||dateOptionalTime"
           },
           "category": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "content": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "exDate": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "exgcode": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "htext": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "paymentDate": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "stat": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "stkno": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "tag": {
              "type": "string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
 }
```

Please kindly advice if my word is : Net Asset and Asset combine, use in Must condition,
if "Asset combine" not in the elasticsearch and "New Asset" in the elasticsearch, using Must condition so all indices can't search?

how to do i want find the word if ones of them inside elasticsearch? 
Cause it can't find "Net Asset" exactly word when i use should condition.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the mapping: `GET index/type/_mapping`

Comment: i'm reedit the coding you need as above

Comment: @SharonWong Can you confirm will you be using `sktno` for searching only `exact terms`? If it is the case then change mapping of `sktno` to `string not_analyzed` otherwise @Richa's answer should help you.

Comment: actually some time searching not only StkNo... Sometime will be multiple value, multiple fields. But terms can't support multi_match..Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since `stkno` is an `analyzed` field and you are applying `terms` query which looks for exact match, you are not able fetch results. Try this instead.

```
 "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "match": {
              "stkno": "Net Asset",
               "operator": "and"
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "stkno": "asset combine",
              "operator": "and"
           }
        }
     ],
     "must": [
        {
           "range": {
              "CDate": {
                 "gte": "2015-01-01",
                 "lte": "2017-06-03T23:59:59"
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: But it still can't find " Net Asset" exactly this two word together. It only can find separate word. I have try to change "bool":{ "should" to "bool":{ "must", it also same result the asset is separate. My indices have exactly word " Net Asset", but it can't find

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: @Richa if he wants to match `exact terms` then isn't it better to make `sktno` to `not_analyzed` field and use `terms` query only.

Comment: @avr: you are right. But that would not allow `case-insensitive` search then.

Comment: @Richa If it is `exact term` we don't have to bother about `case`